# Is $\{0\}/I$ an ideal in quotient ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with ideal $I \neq \{0\}$. Is $\{0\}/I$ an ideal of $R/I$? I know that $I$ is supposed to be an ideal (and hence a subset) of $R$ according to the definition of a quotient ring. But $\{0\}/I = \{0+I\} = \{I\} = \{i+I\ \mid i \in I \} = I/I$. So if these two objects are the same, what's going on? Any help understanding why this does not make sense would be appreciated.

Comment: Normally you see this described as follows: $J/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$ when $J$ is an ideal of $R$ containing $I$. Furthermore, all the ideals of $R/I$ are gotten in this way. This is essentially the correspondence principle (from groups) carried over to the world of rings.

Comment: Anyway, for $M/N$ to exist in algebra we always require $N\subseteq M$. This does not hold with $\{0\}/I$. If you try and describe 
$$J/I=\{j+I\in R/I\mid j\in J\}$$ more generally, you simply get $(J+I)/I$ with 
$$J+I=\{i+j\in R\mid i\in I, j\in J\}$$ when $I\subseteq J+I$.
To get a list of all the ideals of $R/I$ in the form $J/I$ the condition $I\subseteq J$ is imposed to avoid duplications.

Comment: The quotient ring $\pi: R \to R/I$ is precisely the ring that treats all elements of $I$ as zero. That's why there's this similarity. I think the other commenter is correct about the notation (I have not seen it much) as it would reflect the correspondence principle. This statement would be $I = \pi^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is the description in your first sentence biconditional?

Comment: @A.B I'm not sure what you mean. Usually $J/I$ is not even defined unless $I\subseteq J$. You can try to use the recipe in my second comment, but it is A) unnecessary and B) in my humble opinion also a bit misleading. My opinion here is admittedly colored by years of experience of not seeing it done any other way.

Comment: We have the natural projection $\pi:R\to R/I$. Because it is a **surjective** homomorphism of rings we have that $\pi(J)$ is an ideal of $R/I$ for **all** ideals $J$ of $R$. Hence what you want to denote by $\{0\}/I$ I woud denote $\pi(\{0\})$. But, the ideas of correspondence principle would rewrite that as $I/I$ anyway.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I was unclear. What I mean is, when you write "J/I is an ideal of R/I when J is an ideal of R containing I", can you say both that J/I is an ideal of R/I implies J is an ideal of R containing I, AND, J is an ideal of R containing I implies J/I is an ideal of R/I. I agree that only the first one really makes sense, but can you prove the second by treating J/I as a "subset" of R/I and showing that it must be an ideal?

Comment: @A.B, to answer your question in your comment above, yes. The subset $J/I$ of $R/I$ is closed under addition and multiplication precisely because $J$ is closed under addition and multiplication. Explicitly, we have that $(j_1 + I) + (j_2 + I) = (j_1 + j_2) + I$ is in $J/I$ because $j_1 + j_2$ is in $J$ for any elements $j_1, j_2 \in J$ and $(r + I)(j + I) = rj + I$ is in $J/I$ because $rj$ is in $J$ for any elements $r \in R$ and $j \in J.$

Answer (score 2):

Lets fix notation. $R$ is a ring, $I\subseteq R$ an ideal. So far so good. Now we form the quotient ring $R/I=\{x+I\ |\ x\in R\}$. It is typical at this point to assume that $I\subseteq R$, ergo $\{0\}/I$ doesn't really make sense unless $I=\{0\}$.

However there is a way to make this sensible. Consider the quotient homomorphism $\pi:R\to R/I$, $\pi(x)=x+I$. Then given any subset $A\subseteq R$ we can write $A/I$ meaning $\pi(A)$. However I wouldn't use "$A/I$" notation in this case, since typically quotients are reserved for the "$I\subseteq A$" case.

I think it is a good place to mention the correspondence theorem: let $R$ be a ring and $I\subseteq R$ an ideal. Write

$$Ideals(R, I)=\{J\subseteq R\ |\ J\text{ is an ideal and }I\subseteq J\}$$

Now let $I\subseteq R$ be a fixed ideal. Define

$$\Theta:Ideals(R, I)\to Ideals(R/I, 0)$$
$$\Theta(J)=J/I=\pi(J)$$

Here "$0$" on the right side means the zero ideal in $R/I$, i.e. $\{0+I\}$.

The theorem states that $\Theta$ is a well defined bijection. In particular ideals of $R/I$ are fully described by ideals of $R$ containing $I$ and vice versa.

> So if these two objects are the same, what's going on?

What exactly surprises you? That a function maps two subsets into the same subset? Here are few examples:

1. $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=(p)$ for prime $p$, then any ideal $J=(n)$ with $p$ not dividing $n$ will give $\pi(J)=R/I$.
2. $R$ any ring, $I\subseteq R$ any ideal, $A\subseteq I$ any subset, including $A=\{0\}$. Then $\pi(A)=\{0+I\}$.